# Python library to detect a bank/financial institution name in a string

Tags: text-mining, text-filter

I would like to extract bank names from a given text like wells Fargo, chase....is there a python library for this? I know there is entity tagger in space and flair but they only identify the entity (org/person)

Comment: Have you tried creating a list of bank names and using the regex python module to extract the bank names from the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you can use regex but you would need to define a set of rules for it. You can try with [LexNLP](https://github.com/LexPredict/lexpredict-lexnlp) which is trained on legal documents and use it to extract data type like address, companies and persons.

Answer (score 0):

It might be solved with Name Entity Recognition

There you go an example using spacy. I highly recommend you to check its [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101).

The disadvantage of this approach is that it might be computationally expensive and time-consuming

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion")

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried lg model as well. Too many false positives. Try this give Xxxx xxx, this will be classified as person. Not sure what exactly the algo logic is